# How to input words from a file into a vector of type class?

Tags: c++, vector

For my upcoming project in my computer science class, we have to make a star wars quiz game. Here is the project description:

> The file star_wars.txt contains characters' names and the episode they first appeared in (this is chronological based on the release date - 4,5,6,1,2,3). You will populate a vector called cast with the contents of star_wars.txt. The cast vector is of type Character. The class Character has attributes matching the star_wars.txt file: first name, last name, episode. The program will ask the user what episode the character first appeared in. Tell the user if they are correct or incorrect. Keep track of how many they get correct, and give them a ranking based on their score.
>
> Example of star_wars.txt:
>
> Admiral Ackbar 6
>   Lando Calrissian 5
>   etc...

How would I put this file into a vector and display only the first and last name when asking the question?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Character
{
  private:
    int score;


    int episode;
    int guess;
  public:
    void readIn(vector<Character>&cast);
    void readOut();
    string first;
    string last;
};


int main()
{
  Character ch; 
  vector<Character> cast; 
  cout<<"Welcome to the star wars quiz! I will tell you a character and you have to tell me what episode they first appeared in. Lets play!"<<endl;
  ch.readIn(cast); 
  cout<<ch.first<<endl;


  return 0;
}

void Character::readIn(vector<Character>&cast)
{
  ifstream myFile("star_wars.txt");

  while ( !myFile.eof() )
  {
    myFile>>first;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will only go over the reading in of the input.  Displaying should be simple enough to figure out on your own.

What you can do is create an `operator >>` for your `Character` class:

```
#include <istream>
#include <string>

class Character
{
  private:
    int score;
    int guess;

  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Character& ch);
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    int episode;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Character& ch)
{
    is >> ch.first >> ch.last >> ch.episode;
    return is;
}
```

Once you have this, then you can use `>>` to input to a Character, like this:

```
int main()
{
    Character ch;
    cin >> ch;
}
```

Note that I moved the `episode` to the `public` section, but you should really have public `get` and `set` functions for these items, as well as place those members in the `private` section.

Also, you don't want a vector within the class.  What you want to do is have a way to input the items into a vector from outside the class.  You can do it the long way:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("myinputfile.txt");
    std::vector<Character> vCh;
    while (ifs)
    {
        Character ch;  
        ifs >> ch;  // read a line into ch
        vCh.push_back(vCh);  // add this to the vector
    }
}
```

Or the sophisticated way:

```
#include <iterator>
//...
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("myinputfile.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<Character> fileStart(ifs), fileEnd;
    std::vector<Character> vCh(FileStart, fileEnd);
}
```

[Here is a live example](http://ideone.com/C9hv73)

Note that the above example shows an overloading of both `operator >>` and `operator <<` for output.  I won't go over every single line as to what it does, but you can do your own research as to what is being done.